# JSHint: Allow empty return statements with ASI

Tags: javascript, jshint

In my JavaScript I want to have a function exit early if certain conditions are not met, like in the following example.

```
(function () {
  var something = false

  if (!something) return

  doMoreStuff()
}())
```

I'm ommitting semicolons out of preference and it works just fine (the above snippet works as expected).

JSHint keeps giving me the error `Line breaking error 'return'`. While this can be fixed by including a semicolon after the return statement, I'd rather keep semicolons out of my script.

Is there any option I can set to allow for an empty return at the end of a line without a semicolon?

Comment: `if (!something) { return }`

Comment: @alex23 This is not the same. My snippet returns `undefined`, yours returns `false`.
@FabrícioMatté This is similar to adding a semicolon at the end. While it is correct, it's not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: JavaScript is a functional language and functions in FP gotta return a value. AFAIS you're trying to emulate a procedural language that just ...returns. But that's not JavaScript's cup of tea. For the same reason, I'd stay out of `return undefined` altogether: `return false` or `return null` are much more meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any option I can set to allow for an empty return at the end of a line without a semicolon?

No, there is not. Here's the JSHint [code for handling `return` statements](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/src/stable/jshint.js#L3714):

```
stmt("return", function () {
    if (this.line === state.tokens.next.line) {
        //...   
    } else {
        nolinebreak(this); // always warn (Line breaking error)
    }
    // ...
})
```

If there is no semicolon or value following the `return` statement it will always enter the `else` condition and always warn.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use `return null` or `return undefined`.

Comment: Which would be the same as ending the line with the return statement itself.

Comment: `return undefined` is the equivalent to a single `return`.